# SAP script Alignment is not correct in test environment

Tags: abap

I have created work order print layout in sap script which is working perfectly in Development environment, but alignment is not proper in test environment.

Please advise.How can i fix this issue?

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be related to printer driver. 
Every printer has different capability for margin.

Can you check that dev and test environment has same printer?

On the other hand, sapscript is somewhat old, we only use it for barcode printers. 
I prefer to use smart forms.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the paragraph formats are the same in each system.